# Why does free fail to dealloc memory used for sqlite3 errors?

Tags: c++, sqlite, malloc, valgrind

I have this simple program that opens the `data.db` and executes a single query, it compiles without any errors or warnings but when running it with valgrind it states that there is memory leak

```
==1839== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1839==     in use at exit: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==1839==   total heap usage: 215 allocs, 214 frees, 126,688 bytes allocated
==1839== 
==1839== 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==1839==    at 0x48407B4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
==1839==    by 0x109320: main (in /home/test/Desktop/sqlite_example/app)
==1839== 
==1839== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1839==    definitely lost: 1,024 bytes in 1 blocks
==1839==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1839==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1839==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1839==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

this is the code generating the memory leak

```
int main()
{
    sqlite3 * db;
    char path[] = "data.db";
    int rc = sqlite3_open_v2(path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, nullptr);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to open %s\n", path);
        return 1;
    }
    char sql[] = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  groups (group_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL);";
    char * err = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1024);
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, nullptr,nullptr,&err);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to execute query {%s}\n", sql);
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }
    free(err);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

I check the sqlite docs and there are `sqlite3_malloc` and `sqlite3_free` but using those does not solve the problem either

Comment: You're not supposed to allocate memory for `err`.

Comment: `sqlite3_exec` doesn't work the way you think it does. The correct usage goes something like this: `char* err = nullptr; sqlite3_exec(..., &err); DoSomethingWith(err); sqlite3_free(err);` You don't allocate memory for `err`; the function does if necessary, and you then deallocate it.

Comment: In any case, you program as written would leak that memory. You are only freeing it when the error has **not** occurred, in which case `err` would be null anyway. You aren't freeing the memory allocated for the error message precisely in the case when there's an error and there would be an error message. Why are you even passing the last parameter, when you aren't doing anything with the error message? You can pass null there.